# Im new to creating app using java on android studio. Im creating splash screen but not works as i expected

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The splash screen should move towards up and down, then go to the next screen. however, it just change the screen normally. the problem i think maybe between the handler and the animate splashscreen. this is my splash.java. hoping anyone can help thank you.

```
package com.example.dashboard;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    ImageView logo,splashImg;
    TextView appName;
    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
        appName = findViewById(R.id.appname);
        splashImg = findViewById(R.id.img);
        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.lottie);


        splashImg.animate().translationY(-1600).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(3000);
        logo.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(3000);
        appName.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(3000);
        lottieAnimationView.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(3000);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }

}
```

Comment: The apps also running smoothly so i cannot detect the problems, stack trace also not showing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you start another `Activity` at the same time you play your animation. Notice the `.setStartDelay(3000);` at the end of each of your animation calls.

Just removing this will work. However, there are better ways to handle this.

One of the ways would be to override the `onAnimationEnd` method of your longest animation so that it either changes the `Activity` immediately or the change is delayed starting from that point in time. This will look something like this:

```
splashImg.animate().translationY(-1600).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much ! really appreciate it